# Transmission and scattering minimisation for an Aluminum thin film mirror

Tags: optics, reflection

I am using a Tungsten boat to deposit a thin film of Aluminum for optical mirror applications. I noticed that the laser light goes through the film at thickness of $5\cdot 10^3-13\cdot 10^3Å$, albeit it is less at $13\cdot 10^3Å$.

[image]

Is it normal? The evaporation rate is $100Å/s$.

See the picture below, laser is pointed at the front side, picture taken at the backside. Aluminum at front. Thickness $5\cdot 10^3-13\cdot 10^3Å$  Angstroms. Why is light going through aluminum ? What can I do to avoid the transmission

Comment: Are you sure the film is actually that thick? Is the deposited film continuous and smooth? Are you using a sticking layer for the deposition? Have you checked the optical characteristics of aluminum at the wavelength of interest?

Comment: Did you have a witness plate in during the sputtering run so that you could confirm the thickness by profilometry, or did you assume that the evaporation rate was 100 A/s? Also, some amount of the aluminum undoubtedly oxidized into transparent alumina on exposure to air. Any estimate how thick the aluminum layer is after oxidation of the surface?

Comment: It is thermal evaporation, not sputter. I have thickness monitor gauge during evaporation.

Comment: I use laser to see the transmission, the transmission rate is very small under order 6, but visual.

Answer (score 0):

The optical  transmission of this thickness of aluminium is zero.